# TextField is returning nil when it is empty

Tags: ios, ios7

I am preparing my app to iOS7 and have a weird problem:

When I am trying to get an empty TextField text I get "nil", while in the past it used to return @"" (empty string).

Is that a formal change or bug ?

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a formal change from iOS6 to iOS7. The text field used to return an empty string, but now you have a `nil` string instead.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf;

// iOS6
if (![self.tf.text isEqualToString:@""]){

// iOS7    
if (self.tf.text != nil && ![self.tf.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

Answer (score 6):

Another thing which I think you can do is :-

```
if([self.tf.text length] != 0)
{
// do whatever
}
```

The above will handle both empty strings as well as nil. Since sending a length message to nil returns 0.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Its a formal Change. So you need to handle like this

```
// For iOS 6
if (![self.tf.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
}

// For iOS 7    
if (self.tf.text != nil && [self.tf.text length] != 0)
{
}
```

or

This condition for both iOS 7 and earlier version.

```
if([self.tf.text length] != 0)
{
// do your stuff
}
```